# Task Manager disabled by your administrator

Tags: windows, windows-10, task-manager

Recently, I tried to open the Task Manager in Windows 10, I found the Task Manager option disabled (Task Manager word is dark instead of white). I tried to open it via a command prompt by typing taskmgr.exe and I see this message: Task Manager disabled by your administrator. Is there a solution to this problem with the new Windows installation?

Comment: What is unclear? I assume this is in an office and not home machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask your company / institution Administrator. Task Manager works perfectly on any machine where it has not been disabled by Group Policy.

Comment: The problem occurred on my own PC, and I am already an administrator on the computer. How I know that the Task Manager disabled by Group Policy? (Sorry, I've heard about Group Policy before but I don't know how to use it to solve the problem)

Comment: That is indeed strange, especially on a new installation. Look in Windows 10 Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) and check for:   Cofigure User Configuration, Policies, Adminstrative Templates, System, Ctrl Alt Del Option, Remove Task Manager   change to Not Configured .  Close out, restart and test.

Comment: That should be User Configuration (not Computer Configuration).   Sorry - I should not trust to memory

Comment: The problem has been SOLVED! thank you, man :)              Is there a solution to this problem with the new Windows installation?       I was meaning: Is there any solution to fix this problem without a new Windows installation. Anyway, My problem FIXED :D

Comment: You are very welcome and I was pleased to assist you.